# not getting facebook contacts in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get all contacts with numbers. I am doing following code.  problem is only that i am getting all the contacts but i am not getting mobile numbers of all facebook contacts. what can i do to show that facebook contacts also .

```
        cons.SearchCompleted += newEventHandler <ContactsSearchEventArgs(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

        cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1"  );



        void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {

           foreach (Contact con in e.Results)
             { 
                  if (con.PhoneNumbers.Count()>0)
                  { }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can only get friends who authorized your App too since v2.0 - only with an App created before end of April 2014 (v1.0). But it will stop returning all friends after April 2015.
- You can´t get phone numbers of friends, that was never possible. You can´t even get the phone number of the authorized user.